# How to get active filters in catalog/layer/view.phtml

Tags: magento-1.9, layered-navigation

I want to get catalog search `active filters` in `catalog/layer/view.phtml`.

How to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get `active filter` in `catalog/layer/view.phtml` below code is working for me :

```
...
$active_filters = $this->getLayer()->getState()->getFilters();
foreach($active_filters as $filter)
{
    $attributeModel = $filter->getFilter()->getAttributeModel();
    ...
}
...
```

Comment: how to get current product in that file?